# Как разделить строку в список через разделитель "* 123"

Tags: python

У меня есть строка: `Ice Command Center*    2Lava Command Center*    3`

Мне нужен список типа: `["Ice Command Center","Lava Command Center"]`

Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: опиши понятней, как из исходной строки получается нужный список

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
import re
a = "Ice Command Center*    2Lava Command Center*    3Lorem Ipsum*  4Foobar*                     5"
res = [x for x in re.split(r"\*\s+\d+",a) if len(x)]
print(res)
```

> ['Ice Command Center', 'Lava Command Center', 'Lorem Ipsum', 'Foobar']

Comment: Как вариант тоже самое можно так: `res = list(filter(None, re.split(r"\*\s+\d+",a)))`